# Custom WebDriver cannot interact with Selenium Actions methods

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have had to use the Selenium Actions class to use the doubleclick method to interact with some of the elements on my page. This was working fine with the WebDriver (`driver = DriverFactory.open(browserType);`) but when I convert it to my own custom WebDriver below, the double click is not performed.

When I ran in debug mode I could see that with the custom driver the doubleclick method was called, but the mouse was evaluated as null.

Does anyone know why my custom driver doesn't work with Actions?

```
package utilities;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class CustomWebDriver implements WebDriver, JavascriptExecutor
{
    private WebDriver driver;

    private boolean hasQuit = false;

    public CustomWebDriver(String browserType) 
    {
        driver = DriverFactory.open(browserType);
        hasQuit = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void get(String url)
    {
        driver.get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public String getCurrentUrl()
    {
        return driver.getCurrentUrl();
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return driver.getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public List<WebElement> findElements(By by)
    {
        return driver.findElements(by);
    }

    @Override
    public WebElement findElement(By by)
    {
        return driver.findElement(by);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageSource()
    {
        return driver.getPageSource();
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
    {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void quit()
    {
        driver.quit();
        hasQuit = true;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getWindowHandles()
    {
        return driver.getWindowHandles();
    }

    @Override
    public String getWindowHandle()
    {
        return driver.getWindowHandle();
    }

    @Override
    public TargetLocator switchTo()
    {
        return driver.switchTo();
    }

    @Override
    public Navigation navigate()
    {
        return driver.navigate();
    }

    @Override
    public Options manage()
    {
        return driver.manage();
    }

    public boolean hasQuit()
    {
        return hasQuit;
    }

    @Override
    public Object executeScript(String script, Object... args)
    {
        return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, args);
    }

    @Override
    public Object executeAsyncScript(String script, Object... args)
    {
        return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(script, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom WebDriver needs to implement the [Interactive](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/762c0e91aab60c29d7f92845dd52efc817e41df1/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Interactive.java) interface. The [Actions](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/762c0e91aab60c29d7f92845dd52efc817e41df1/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.java) class calls the `perform()` method of this interface in its own perform() method.

You might also need to implement the [HasInputDevices](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/762c0e91aab60c29d7f92845dd52efc817e41df1/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasInputDevices.java) interface.

You could also have extended the existing [RemoteWebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/762c0e91aab60c29d7f92845dd52efc817e41df1/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java) and customized it. Spares you from duplicating methods.